# H-4 extension granted after moving out of US - can I reenter to visit?

Tags: usa, visa-extensions, h1b-visas

I used to reside in the USA under a H-4 (spouse) visa, but recently accepted a job abroad and moved out of the country. Just before that, my spouse and I both applied for visa extensions, as our visas were about to expire. My spouse had their application approved fairly quickly, but mine took so long I ended up leaving the country before the application result came out.

Now, after living and working abroad for about two months, I found out that my H-4 extension has been granted. My intuitive understanding is that I *should* be able to claim and use this H-4 visa to visit my spouse, since it does not impose any conditions of continued US residence (that I could find). I know H-4 visas prohibit the visa holder from working while in the US, but I understand it should be fine if I visit during my vacations, for example. However, I could not find any rules clearly stating whether this is possible or not.

My questions are:

**1) Do I have the right to claim and use this H-4 visa to visit the USA while residing and working abroad?**

**2) Have other people in similar situations successfully claimed and used their visas to visit while residing and working abroad?**

---

### EDIT:

Thank you to [user102008](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/168992/105030) for pointing out the difference between the **visa** and the **status** - I had the two mixed up, and it got very confusing because of that.

In case it helps someone else, here are some definitions taken from [this USCIS document](https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/document/foia/Nonimmigrant_Services.pdf) (page 18):

> *A* ***visa*** [...] *allows the person to travel to the U.S. and apply for entry in that nonimmigrant category*.  The visa is valid for a certain length of time, and you may use it to apply for entry while the visa is valid.
>
> *A person who is admitted is granted a particular **status** based on the visa and is admitted for a specific period of time.* [...] The I-94 record shows the nonimmigrant category or other status in which the nonimmigrant was admitted and how long the nonimmigrant is authorized to stay.  The admisstion period often does not match the validity of the visa because the visa serves a different purpose.

To recap my question, but with the proper terms:

1. I was residing in the US under a H-4 **status**;
2. I applied for an extension of status in timely manner, but **both my status and visa expired before I received a decision** [see side note below];
3. After departing from the US, I received a notice that the extension of **status** request was granted;
4. However, because my old visa expired, I need a valid **visa** to re-enter the country.

### In conclusion

I need to obtain a new H-4 visa. I'm still not sure whether the new status can facilitate me getting a new visa or whether I have to submit a new application from scratch, but that's a topic for another question.

I would still be happy to hear from other people who have been through the same situation!

---

*Side note:* as per page 7 of the same USCIS document linked above, when my status expired I became officially *out of status*, but I did not accrue *unlawful presence for purposes of inadmissibility*:

> **What if I file on time but USCIS doesn’t make a decision before my I-94 expires?** Your lawful nonimmigrant status ends, and you are out of status, when your admission stamp date or your Form I-94 expires, even if you have timely applied to extend the period of your nonimmigrant status. [...]
>
> As a matter of discretion, however, DHS may defer bringing a removal proceeding against you until after USCIS decides your application for an extension of your nonimmigrant status. Also, while you are not actually in a lawful nonimmigrant status, you do not accrue “unlawful presence” for purposes of inadmissibility under section 212(a)(9)(B) of the Act, while your extension application is pending.

This is important because it can look like I overstayed my visit. Therefore, one should keep the documents related to their extension of status application and show them upon their next reentry in the USA, as described on page 6 of the aforementioned document:

> **What if I file on time for an extension, but I leave the U.S. before USCIS makes a decision on my application?** If you leave the U.S. before a decision is made on your application to extend and you plan to return to the U.S. in the future, please keep a copy of your application plus the receipt notice to show to the Immigration Inspector on your return travel to the U.S.  Otherwise, you may be denied entry for overstaying on your last visit.

Comment: You apply for a new visa the same way you applied for the old one: fill out the DS-160 form and provide the documents they ask for to support your eligibility for the H-4. Note that the stuff they ask for may include things documenting your spouse's current status and employment, but is less likely to include anything about your own now-abandoned extension application, i.e. they'll be more interested in your spouse's current status than your own former status. That said, you should take your extension approval to the visa interview in case the overstay comes up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You applied for an extension of your H4 *status*. Status is something which only exists while you're in the US. When you left the US, you ceased to have any status.

Except after trips of less than 30 days to Canada or Mexico (in which case you can enter on Automatic Revalidation), the next time you enter the US, you must enter on the basis of a valid US visa. This could be an H4 visa, or some other visa, and you will be admitted to a new status from scratch, with the status having the same category as your visa, and for a new duration based on the rules of admission for that visa. (Or if you are entering on the Visa Waiver Program, you will be admitted to that status from scratch. Or if you are a Canadian citizen, you don't need a visa, but everything else I said about being admitted to a new status from scratch applies.)

Assuming that the officer on your next entry decides to admit you, the new status and duration you get is not related to what status you had during your past stay (and whether it was extended and/or changed); it is simply based on the visa you present on that entry. There is no point to approve or deny an Extension of Stay or Change of Status application after you have already left the US, because the decision makes no difference -- you are going to be admitted on the basis of your visa on your next entry anyway, not on the basis of your previous status. (And you do not accrue unlawful presence while a timely-filed, non-frivolous Extension of Stay or Change of Status application is pending anyway, so an approval or denial after you left makes no difference for the purposes of unlawful presence either.) Normally, they would automatically consider your Extension of Stay application abandoned if you left while it was pending; the fact that they approved it is probably an oversight. But again, as I explained, the approval doesn't matter.

Your ability to seek entry into the US into H4 status only depends on you having an unexpired H4 visa (or being a Canadian citizen with no visa), and your spouse being in H1b status. It does not depend on whether your previous Extension of Stay application was approved, denied, or abandoned. Yes, you can use H4 status for visits, long or short.

Comment: This answer is simply wrong.  Whilst many requests for extension of status are considered Abandoned if you leave the US before they are approved, this is NOT the case for H-1B and H-4 status. This answer will be better answer on Expats where people are more likely to understand the specifics of H-1B/H-4 visas.

Comment: @Doc: An approval or denial of extension of status after the person has already left the US would serve no purpose whatsoever. I do understand how it works and there is no difference between H1b/H4 status and other statuses in this regard. If you have another opinion then please point out a single difference it would make to approve or deny an extension of status after the person has already left the US.

Comment: https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/can-i-travel-while-h-1b-application-is-pending-at-uscis.html or any other number of sites available via google.  If you still have a valid visa stamp, you can enter using that stamp but with the extended status. If you do not have a valid visa stamp, you can use the approved extension (I-797) to obtain a new visa stamp whilst abroad.

Comment: @Doc: You are probably confusing status with H1b petitions. When a company files I-129 to petition someone for H1b, if the person is in the US, the company can optionally request EOS/COS on the I-129. If the company requests this and the person leaves the US while it is pending, the EOS/COS is abandoned, but the H1b petition continues to be adjudicated (since someone doesn't need to be in the US to be petitioned for H1b), and, if otherwise qualifies, the H1b petition will be approved. An H1b petition approval without an EOS/COS approval comes on an I-797B, which does not come with an I-94.

Comment: @Doc: The next time this person enters the US, they will enter on the basis of their unexpired H1b visa, and the rules for H1b admission is to admit them until the end of the H1b petition. If they have the approval for the new H1b petition, they will be admitted until the end of that. This has absolutely nothing to do with the previous H1b EOS. Similarly, an H4 EOS/COS is abandoned if they leave the US while it is pending. The next time they enter the US, they will enter on the basis of their H4 visa, and the rules for H4 admission say to admit them until the end of the H1b principal's status.

Comment: @Doc: So if the H1b worker has status until the end of the H1b petition, the H4 will be admitted until the end of the H1b petition also. Again, this has absolutely nothing to do with the previous H4 EOS/COS, which was abandoned.

Comment: H4 EOS/AOS are NOT abandoned when you leave the country! See CFR 245.2 (a)(4)(ii)(C)

Comment: @Doc: Again, you have not provided a single situation where EOS/COS approval or denial after the person leaves the US would make any difference. Your statement "you can enter using that stamp but with the extended status" is false if you are talking about actual status, since "status" does not exist when the person is outside the US. You are talking about H1b and H4 being able to enter on the basis of their visas and the H1b petition approval (regardless of whether it comes with EOS/COS approval).

Comment: @Doc: Your statement "you can use the approved extension (I-797) to obtain a new visa stamp whilst abroad" is again about the H1b petition approval (I-797A or I-797B), not about EOS/COS approval (which only I-797A carries, but not I-797B). Also, H4 does not have petitions, and it is clear that they are using the H1b worker's H1b petition approval, not anything to do with the H4.

Comment: user102008's answer is correct, from my understanding, but I had to dig deeper and clarify some concepts in my head for their answer to make sense; please see edit to question. I think the issue here is that both my visa *and* status were expired when I left the country, but because I thought they were different names for the same thing I did not formulate my question correctly, and that lead to some confusion in the comments. The link on Doc's comment indeed mentions obtaining a new visa, so I think we are all in agreement here :) thank you all for your help

Comment: @Doc 8 CFR 245.2(a)(4)(ii)(C) concerns only AOS applications, not EOS applications.  We're talking about an EOS application here, so 8 CFR 245.2(a)(4)(ii)(C) doesn't apply.  See https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/8/245.2